# Android Development: App is lagging when ontouch listener is inactive

Tags: android, lag, ontouch

I haven't been able to find a question online similar to this, so I thought I would submit the question. In most cases it seems people have the opposite problem were lag may be occurring during a touch event, but I am seeing the exact opposite. I am creating an air hockey game and each frame the pieces are moved based on their current parameters, and the game is redrawn while in the background the override ontouch listener is looking for motion events. The thing is there is noticeable lag when there is no fingers touching the screen and just watching the animated pieces, but as long as there is any form of motion event happening, if ontouch is being called, then the animation is smooth. I really can not figure why this is, my best educated guess is the interrupt that is checking if ontouch should be called is consuming more resources than it should, but I know nothing about how to modify or check the ontouch interrupt behavior at all so hopefully someone might know.

A little more background on how everything is organized. The overall class is located in Main.java, it is created here and requests the Context view, the game class is an extension of ImageView. The game class has a @override OnTouchEvent, which has all the defintions for what to do depending on what state and what motion event. The class also has a draw method, and at the end of the method it calls h.postDelayed(r, FRAME_RATE); where r is a Runnable with @Override public void run() which just calls invalidate();. h is just a handler that is initialized in the class. So each time the game is drawn invalidate will be called after the FRAME_RATE elapse time of 10ms, which tells the game to redraw. All the move functions for the game are also called from the draw method. The OnTouch is happening all along side this process so why would it be smoother if on OnTouch is being called rather than checking if its true, it all seems counter intuitive but I'm sure there is a logical reason. Lastly the lag time was measurable using the system clock and was time dependent based on where exactly it was called. It just showed an increase in passing time between the games move function when a touch event was not occurring.

Sorry for the long response without much actual code context, I hope it is descriptive enough. The code its self is rather long so I didn't think it would help to post that, but if needed I can do better at re posting some pseudo code with the visualized hierarchy. Thank you for any help and suggestions for this problem. It would be great to be able to understand why it is happening.

Here is the code, I was trying to fit it into a comment didn't realize you had to post it by editing the original post.

```
public class Main extends Activity {

Game game;
private Menus menus; // contains menu info
int menu; //keep track of what menu you are at

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    game = new Game(this);
    setContentView(game);

  }
@Override
public void onDestroy() { 
   super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    ..some code here to process photo files
}

//get the orientation of loaded pictures
public static int getOrientation(Context context, Uri photoUri) {
    /* it's on the external media. */
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(photoUri,
            new String[] { MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION }, null, null, null);

    if (cursor.getCount() != 1) {
        return -1;
    }

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getInt(0);
}




public void Keyboard()
{
    use keyboard listener and perform some actions if...
}

public class Game extends ImageView{

            private Game game;

            //Touch Events
            boolean pressed;

            private Context mContext;
            private Handler h;
            private final int FRAME_RATE = 10;  
            boolean initDimension = false;

            //constant for defining the time duration between the click that can be considered as double-tap
            static final int MAX_DURATION = 500;

            Bitmap background;

            int HEIGHT;
            int WIDTH;


    public Game(Context context)  {
                    super(context);      
                    mContext = context;

                    h = new Handler();

                    //ModeInit(); // load up puck game mode
                    menu = 0; //after tap from ontouch changes to menu = 1 for game
          }

             private Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                     @Override
                     public void run() {
                             invalidate();
                     }
             }; 

            @Override
             public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
             { 
                 Switch Statement...
                 CHECK MOTION EVENT TYPE
                    CHECK menu state.. perform action   
             }

             public void ModeInit()
             {  
                 game = new Game( mContext, WIDTH, HEIGHT );   
             }

             protected void onDraw(Canvas c) 
             {

                 if(!initDimension)
                 {
                     WIDTH = this.getWidth();
                     HEIGHT = this.getHeight();
                     initDimension = true;
                 }
                 else
                 {

                     //logo screen
                     if(menu == 0)
                     {
                           menu = menus.DisplayIntro(c);
                     }
                    //game mode
                     else if(menu == 1)
                     {
                           game.paint_game(c);
                           long run_test = System.nanoTime()/1000; 
                           game.Move();
                           Log.d("run time: ",": "+(System.nanoTime()/1000-run_test)); //Ontouch LAG TEST
                     }
                     ... other menu items here
                 }

                h.postDelayed(r, FRAME_RATE);

          }

    }

  }
```

Comment: You'll have better luck if you trim things down to a small amount of code and then post it here.

Comment: Just making sure you are aware of the Google IO sessions on Project Butter: https://youtu.be/Q8m9sHdyXnE and Graphics Performance: https://youtu.be/vQZFaec9NpA. Without code no one can tell what is going on. You might want to look at one of the earliest Android sample apps which did air hockey over bluetooth  - not sure if it works anymore but the source is there:  https://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/source/browse/BTClickLinkCompete/src/net/clc/bt/AirHockey.java

Comment: I wanted to add that the entire base of my code is rooted on this bouncing ball tutorial, http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/bouncing-a-ball-on-androids-canvas/